# counting regexp matches within the method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have some code like below. `comment` method is called whenever some comment occurs in the `html`. Then, I am doing a regexp match, I want to count the number of matches within the parsed comments. Its printing like below

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

what I want is to just print `5` because thats the total number of matches. can someone help pls.

```
class PlainTextExtractor < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document
  def comment(string)
    # I am defining some regexp here 
    m = Regexp.new(re, Regexp::IGNORECASE);
    if m.match(string)
      $count += 1
      puts $count 
    end
  end
end

parser = Nokogiri::HTML::SAX::Parser.new(PlainTextExtractor.new)
parser.parse_memory(html)
```

Comment: Just move your `puts $count` out of the loop. You can put it at the end, after you call the parser.

Comment: simple! this worked. thanks! all for the comments

Comment: I made my comment an answer, in case you decide to accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Just move your `puts $count` out of the loop. You can put it at the end, after you call the parser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the number of matches you can do

```
m = Regexp.new(re, Regexp::IGNORECASE);
puts string.scan(m).length
```

Comment: I tried above suggestion , it printed like this `00000100000100000100000100000

Comment: could you post an example?
Include what your regex is, and the string.

Comment: ok, so parser parsed 29 comments in the html. for each comment 'comment' is called and the regex, which is stored in `re` is searching for pattern ` HouseAd: [false]` . from the 29 line of comments it printed 1 wherever there was a match and rest 0's. regex is `re1='(HouseAd)'re2='(:)'re3='.*?'re4='(\\[false\\])'
re=(re1+re2+re3+re4)`   let me know if it makes sense or if you need anything else. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make your class count the number of matches internally in an instance variable, eg @count.  Then use attr_reader to create a method allowing you to read its value at the end.  Also you don't need a global variable.  Example (not tested):

```
class PlainTextExtractor < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document
  attr_reader :count
  def comment(string)
    # I am defining some regexp here 
    m = Regexp.new(re, Regexp::IGNORECASE);
    if m.match(string)
      @count += 1
    end
  end
end

pt_extractor = PlainTextExtractor.new
parser = Nokogiri::HTML::SAX::Parser.new(pt_extractor)
parser.parse_memory(html)
puts pt_extractor.count
```